# Imagem que insiro no body do email usando TinyMCE não aparece no e-mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, envio-de-email, tinymce

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail com uma ou mais imagens que fiz upload usando o textarea do tinymce, onde eu escrevo o e-mail a ser enviado, eu escrevo o que quero e dou upload na imagem, ela aparece lá porém não envia no e-mail, quando olho o e-mail enviado só aparece o que foi digitado e não a imagem

Código da função que envia o e-mail:

```
function send_mail($con){
    if(isset($_POST['env']) && $_POST['env'] == "email"){


        $destinos= explode(',',$_POST['destinos']);


        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Username = 'envioemail347@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = 'senha';
        $mail->Port = 465;
        #$mail->Port = 587;

        for($i=0; $i<count($destinos); $i++){

        $mail->setFrom('envioemail347@gmail.com', 'Stephanto');
        $mail->addAddress($destinos[$i]);
        $mail->addReplyTo('drawertti347@gmail.com');

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['assunto'];
        $mail->Body = $_POST['mensagem'];

    }

        if(!$mail->send()){
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Erro ao enviar o E-mail! </div><br>";
            echo "Erro: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Codigo da pagina de envio de e-mails:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js"></script>

  <script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | image code',


    images_upload_url: '../lib/upload.php',


    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', '../lib/upload.php');

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }

            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(json.location);
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
    },
});
</script>



<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Destinatários</label>
    <input type="text" name="destinos" class="form-control" value="<?php get_emails($con); ?>"><br>

    <label>Assunto</label>
    <input type="text" name="assunto" class="form-control"><br>

    <label>Mensagem</label>
    <textarea name="mensagem" rows="20"></textarea><br>

    <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="" value="Enviar e-mail" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="env" value="email">
</form>
        <p align="left"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='index.php?pagina=inicio'">Cadastrar e-mails</button></p>

</div>

<?php send_mail($con); ?>
```

Código da upload.php

```
<?php

$accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://107.161.82.130", "http://codexworld.com");


$imageFolder = "../imagens/";

reset($_FILES);
$temp = current($_FILES);
if(is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){

        if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)){
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        }else{
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
            return;
        }
    }


    if(preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])){
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }


    if(!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))){
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }


    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);


    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
} else {

    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
}
?>
```

Comment: Já tive esse problema, e dava porque minha imagem não estava hospedada no servidor, caso você esteja fazendo local pode ser esse problema, eu resolvi colocando minha imagem no servidor do site, e ai colocava o link dela.

Comment: @Larissasilva tem como fazer isso usando localhost? é somente para um projeto escolar não algo que seja necessário hospedar

Comment: Local nunca tentei, mas como é um projeto acadêmico, uma ideia que você pode tentar fazer e vê se funciona, é deixar essa imagem na nuvem, com compartilhamento pra todo mundo, assim você pega o link dela e coloca no seu projeto. Nunca tentei fazer assim, mas pode ser que de certo